# How to get the value of boolean array in android java?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am using a boolean array in my adapter class (extending ArrayAdapter) to store the checked checkox positions. When i print it in the logcat it prints [Z@42067480 every time i check a checkbox. What does it means? How to decode this to get value of a particular checked position? I am new in this.
Also, is there any other alternate to store checked items positions of a custom listview.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are printing the whole boolean array as a String, Instead i am giving you just a example below, you can change it accordingly. Two type of for loop i am using. You can choose one of that.

```
  boolean []arr={true,false,true,true};


            for(boolean boolean1:arr)
            {
                Log.e("",""+boolean1);          
            }
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            Log.e("",""+arr[i]);
        }
```

You can either store the data in arraylist in the loop in which you iterating your boolean array or you can create another. It depends on your choice. I have used the existing for loop. You can create new if want.

```
 ArrayList<Boolean> booleans=new ArrayList<Boolean>();

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                Log.e("",""+arr[i]);
                booleans.add(arr[i]);
            }
```

OR

```
for (boolean b:arr) {
                Log.e("",""+b);
                booleans.add(b);
            }
```

If you have any query, please comment.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. Now what to do if i have to store this array in an ArrayList<Boolean>. I want this arraylist value to get into my main activity.

Comment: Thanks it works. I am posting some more query to you in some time.

Comment: Please Upvote my answer if you liked it. Thanks user3667581 in advance.

Comment: How to open CAB on selection of any single checkbox like gmail app?

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to do. CAB? Thanks.

Comment: I want to show/hide a contextual action bar(CAB) on checkbox selection to perform actions on multiple selected items as in gmail app.

Comment: Please refer this. hope it will help you. http://java.dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68334/discussion-between-user3667581-and-vivek).

Comment: Hi Ashish, Unable to continue the discussion, if you have any other query, you can post. Thanks.

Comment: My aim is to implement gmail like listview in which on checkbox selection a CAB is opened overriding the action bar at top. my code implementation & errors are given in my other question whose link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818646/how-to-get-context-of-an-activity-extending-listfragment-from-its-adapter-class Please give your suggestions about that i you found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the memory location of the array; you are probably doing `myArray.toString()` that is why you see the same thing for all indexes.

As for the best way to store the checkbox state, you should probably use a [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html).

Answer (score 0):

You must be printing the value of checkbox itself. Print checkbox.isChecked().